# Running Windows Command in Java Using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I'm having a little bit of trouble running this confusing windows command from java and I can't find anything that is similar to what I'm trying to do to base my code against.

Basically the windows command kills any PIDs relating to sockets with a CLOSE_WAIT status and related to the specific ip:port specified. My issue is I'm having a hard time getting it to run using Runtime.getRuntime().exec().

```
String[] command = {"cmd /c for /f \"tokens=5\" %a in ('netstat -noa -p tcp ^| find /i \"CLOSE_WAIT\" ^| find /i \""+ip+":443\" ') do if not \"%a\"==\"0\" echo taskkill /pid %a"};     
Process runCommand = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
runCommand.waitFor();
```

While doing this I am current getting the error message:

> class java.io.IOException  Message: Cannot run program "C:/ cmd /c for
>   /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -noa -p tcp ^| find /i "CLOSE_WAIT" ^|
>   find /i "ip:443" ') do if not "%a"=="0" echo taskkill /pid %a":
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try to execute that command in `cmd` first and check whether that command is a valid command or not!

Comment: Have you tried creating a .bat file with your windows command and running the .bat via runtime.exec()?

Comment: Hmm I actually just did and I get a '| was unexpected at this time' error message

I do not want to run it via a bat file because that would involve adding some clutter to my codebase and I need to pass the ip of the system I want to close the socket with. I try and keep as little amount of files as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing a String[] array rather than a single String, you are telling the system to run a single .exe file whose name contains about 144 characters, the first thirteen of which are `cmd /c for /f`.  Obviously there is no .exe file with that name.

One thing you can try is passing that single String to the [exec(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-) method instead of passing an array of Strings.  This may or may not work, as Java will split your string into whitespace-delimited words, and then Windows will heuristically try to figure out what you want.

Another approach that may work is a String array containing 3 elements:

```
String[] command = { "cmd", "/c", "for /f \"tokens=5\" %a in ('netstat -noa -p tcp ^| find /i \"CLOSE_WAIT\" ^| find /i \""+ip+":443\" ') do if not \"%a\"==\"0\" echo taskkill /pid %a" };
```

The best thing to do, in my opinion, is not to rely on cmd.exe for parsing command line arguments.  I suspect Java is at least as efficient at processing text:

```
Collection<String> pids = new ArrayList<>();

ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("netstat.exe", "-noa", "-p", "tcp");
p.inheritIO().redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);
Process netstat = p.start();

try (BufferedReader output =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(netstat.getOutputStream()))) {

    String line;
    while ((line = output.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.toUpperCase().contains("CLOSE_WAIT") &&
            line.contains(ip + ":443")) {

            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            String pid = tokens[4];
            if (!pid.equals("0")) {
                pids.add(pid);
            }
        }
    }
}

if (netstat.waitFor() != 0) {
    throw new IOException("netstat command failed");
}

p.inheritIO();
for (String pid : pids) {
    Process taskkill = p.command("taskkill.exe", "/pid", pid).start();
    taskkill.waitFor();
}
```

If you're using Java 8, you can also use Streams to write code that more closely resembles piped commands:

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("netstat.exe", "-noa", "-p", "tcp");
p.inheritIO().redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);
Process netstat = p.start();

try (BufferedReader output =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(netstat.getOutputStream()))) {

    final ProcessBuilder taskkill = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO();

    output.lines()
        .filter(line -> line.toUpperCase().contains("CLOSE_WAIT") &&
            line.contains(ip + ":443"))
        .map(line -> line.split("\\s+")[4])
        .filter(pid -> !pid.equals("0"))
        .forEach(pid ->
            taskkill.command("taskkill.exe", "/pid", pid).start());
}

if (netstat.waitFor() != 0) {
    throw new IOException("netstat command failed");
}
```